# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single[]' to type 'System.Double[]', why?

Tags: c#

```
double[] vTessTriangles = (double[])swFace.GetTessTriangles(true);
                    double VTTx2 = vTessTriangles[2];
```

Why I get this `InvalidCastExpection`

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single[]' to type
>   'System.Double[]'.

Comment: This is probably because GetTessTriangles returns Single[] instead of Double[]. =) Could you work with Single[], or do you need to cast the result to double[]?

Comment: Apparently swFace.GetTessTriangles(true); return a single and not a double[]. Can you check that method and type of return values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, because you can't cast `single[]` to `double[]`- This should work:

```
float[] vTessTriangles = (float[])swFace.GetTessTriangles(true);
double VTTx2 = vTessTriangles[2];
```

Comment: `System.Single` and `float` are the same type. The cast is a no-op.

Comment: @millimoose - this depends on the definition of `GetTessTriangles`. If it returns an `object`, then the cast is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that Single mean float. What is cast.

Comment: @Henrik: A cast basically means converting from one type to another. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173105(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @TejasSharma - thanks, but what gave you the impression I didn't know this?

Comment: whoops sorry! That was for the guy who posted the question haha

Answer (score 0):

You get that because a `single[]` can't be cast to a `double[]`.  If you could, then that resulting `double[]` would think that every element should be a double.  For fetching elements that's fine; the elements are actually floats, but they can be implicitly converted to doubles.  The problem is with setting elements.  When setting an element the *actual* array can only accept floats, or subtypes of floats, but if you cast it to a `double[]` it thinks you can set a double.  A `double` cannot be implicitly converted to a `float`, so it would be an invalid operation.

In order to save a `single[]` to a `double[]` you need to create a new structure and copy all of the elements over, rather than just casting the whole array.  You could do this yourself, but LINQ can shorten it a bit:

```
double[] vTessTriangles = swFace.GetTessTriangles(true).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```